# How to Access Google Docs Add-on Javascript from Console / Bookmarklet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created and published a Google Docs add-on using Google Apps Script and I want to find a way to trigger some of the functions in my add-on either via a bookmarklet or the directly from the developer console on a Gdoc.

If a have a function called getSelectedText() in my code.js file, how can I fire that function from the developer console, from a bookmarklet or from the address bar? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You might need to use [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). This let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event, like opening a document, occurs. Be noted that simple triggers fire automatically without asking the user for authorization. If you want to call [services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services) that require [authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization), use [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: This doesn't quite work. I've been trying, but I can't get it to do something within my open Google Doc is I launch a web app script with a doGet function in it. I'm trying to figure out a way that I can just click a bookmarklet or inject some javascript with a Chrome extension that will cause my Google Docs add-on to fire up. So far, no luck.